# Finding the sum of a column based on range of a string column

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

I have a *raw* table like below:

| Name | DetailedName | Position_Seqnum | Position_name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | A1eng | 0 | 00-Start here | 1 |
| A1 | A1eng | 53 | 08-Go left | 2 |
| A1 | A1eng | 60 | 99-Stop there | 2 |
| A1 | A1eng | 62 | 101-Go right | 4 |
| B1 | B1eng | 0 | 00- Start here | 4 |
| B1 | B1eng | 1 | 23-Go right | 3 |
| B1 | B1eng | 35 | 98- Stop there | 6 |

**Objective**: For each Name, and for all the position_name *between* Start here and Stop there, I wish to return the total value of the Name.

The *expected* output is like:

| Name | DetailedName | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | A1eng | 5 |
| B1 | B1eng | 13 |

**Explanation of the expected output:**

1. A1 has position_name 00-Start here and 3rd row has position_name 99-Stop there.
2. For all rows i.e (row1 + row2 +row3, position_seqnum 0, 53 and 60), I wish to extract the total value i.e 1+2+2 = 5.

My SQL attempt:

```
SELECT Name, DetailedName, Value
FROM `table` 
WHERE 
AND Position_name between
(trim(Position_name ) = REGEXP_EXTRACT(trim(Position_name ),r".*Start here.*")) 
AND
(trim(Position_name ) =  REGEXP_EXTRACT(trim(Position_name ),r".*Stop there.*"))
AND Value > 0 
order by Name
)
select * from cte
```

What I failed to achieve is how to apply *between* clause over a string column.

Comment: *all the position_name between Start here and Stop there* The term "between" needs in definite rows ordering. What criteria defines this ordering within the group?

Comment: The definite rows ordering would be governed by the Position_seqnum, e.g. for each Name, ordered by Postion_seqnum, having seqeunce_num between Start here and Stop there.

Comment: From your example it seems you are summing _all_ the positions for a route (i.e. "Start here" is always the first position, and "Stop there" is always the last one). So why bother with the `between` part at all?

Comment: "Start here" is always first, yes but "Stop there" might not be the last, there may be more steps for each Name. Thank you for pointing it out, I ll add in the sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this problem following these steps:

- compute a running sum for each "*Name*", ordered by "*Position_Seqnum*"
- apply a `SELF JOIN` where you match "*start*" rows with "*stop*" rows
- subtract start running sum from stop running sum, then add up the start value

Here's the full query:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
           SUM(Value_) OVER(
                PARTITION BY Name 
                ORDER     BY Position_Seqnum
           )                            AS running_sum
    FROM tab
)
SELECT t1.Name, 
       t1.DetailedName,
       t2.running_sum - t1.running_sum + t1.Value_
FROM       cte t1
INNER JOIN cte t2
        ON t1.Name = t2.Name
       AND t1.DetailedName = t2.DetailedName
       AND t1.Position_Name LIKE '%Start%'
       AND t2.Position_Name LIKE '%Stop%'
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nb3qPzz7szUBJE1gs9gVut/0).

**Note**: this solution assumes that you have only one start and one stop for each "*Name*". If you have multiple ones, then you need to use a row number and match row numbers between "*start*"s and "*end*"s.

Answer (score 2):

Below is an approach without **JOIN**

```sql
WITH ranges AS (
  SELECT *,
         LAST_VALUE(IF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(Position_name, r'Start here'), Position_Seqnum, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) OVER w AS start,
         LAST_VALUE(IF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(Position_name, r'Stop there'), Position_Seqnum, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) OVER w AS stop
    FROM sample
  WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Name)
)
SELECT Name, DetailedName, SUM(Value) AS Value
  FROM ranges 
 WHERE Position_Seqnum BETWEEN start AND stop
 GROUP BY 1, 2
;
```

[image]

Comment: Hey @Jaytiger, this seems to be an excellent approach, as removing Joins makes the query optimized and great use of LAST_VALUE, thanks so much!!

Answer (score 2):

> "Start here" is always first, yes but "Stop there" might not be the last, there may be more steps for each Name

So, in this case , even simpler/cheaper

```
select Name, DetailedName, sum(Value) Value from (
  select Name, DetailedName, Value from your_table
  qualify 0 = countif(regexp_contains(Position_name, 'Stop there')) over win
  window win as (partition by name order by Position_Seqnum rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
)
group by Name, DetailedName
```

with output

[image]